# sign of special integral polynomials over roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $h>0$ be a positive odd integer. Let $n=4h^2.$

Let $R(t)=r_0+r_1t+ \cdots + r_{n-1}t^{n-1}$

be a polynomial with integer coefficients in $\{-1,1\}$
such that

$R(\omega)$ is a nonzero integer for all complex $\omega \notin ${-1,1}
such that

(a)

$$
\omega^n=1
$$

and

(b)

$$
R(1) = 2h
$$

Can we deduce that all these integers $R(\omega)$ have the same sign ???

reason: R(t) is the ``representer" polynomial of a circulant $-1,1$
matrix $C$ of order $n$ with first row $(r_0, \ldots,r_{n-1})$.  I am trying
to understand what happens when all the eigenvalues of $C$  (i.e., the $R(\omega)$)
are real.

Comment: Why are you interested in these polynomials? This question is extremely similar to your previous one, and this question is probably too localized for MO. 

Comment: thanks again, have you un example with n >4 ?

Comment: I have not looked at the question properly, but on first glance agree with J.C. Ottem. Without better motivation, these questions just *seem* somewhat random, and generated on a whim rather than for a coherent purpose.

Comment: reason added to question

Comment: Luis, why not "thanks again, have you un example with $n =36$ ?" ?!

Comment: I agree with you wadim...

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of the unknown:
$$
R(t)=\frac{1-x^{16}}{1-x}-12x^8
$$
is a counter-example to your sign expectation. You can easily generalize this to any degree $n=4h^2$.

**Edit.** Igor brings to my attention the fact that the coefficients of $R(t)$ has to be all $\pm1$. For this situation one (including the author) could simply use brute force: if $n=16$, the polynomial of the desired form is a linear combination of the *polynomials* $(1-x^{16})/(1-x^j)$, $(1-x^8)/(1-x^k)$ and $x^8$. Just pick all possible integer combinations with the $\pm1$ restriction on the coefficients and check their values at the 16th roots of unity. This would also suggest how to proceed for the general $n$.

I turn my "answer" to the community wiki mode, so please feel free (if necessary) to add further details.

Comment: I believe the question asks for $\pm 1$ coefficients, so this is not a counterexample.

Comment: I finally realized that there was a pre-question to this question already answered by the (same) unknown. And I would join the above remark of the unknown: it is a strange question without sufficient motivation...

Comment: $16 = 4 \cdot 2^2$  i.e., $h=2$ that is not odd

Comment: Luis, you are kidding! There was already a post which has recognized 2 to be the oddest integer. :-) Too many constraints. Please try yourself to modify everything for $4\cdot3^2$.